# map vectorised terms to the original dataframe

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe column contains domain names i.e. newyorktimes.com. I split by '.' and apply CountVectorizer to "newyorktimes".

The dataframe

```
domain            split          country    
newyorktimes.com  newyorktimes   usa
newyorkreport.com newyorkreport  usa
```

"newyorktimes" is also added as a new dataframe column called 'split'

I'm able to get the term frequencies

```
vectoriser  = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english')
X = vectoriser.fit_transform(df['split'])
features = vectoriser.get_feature_names()
count = x.toarray().sum(axis=0)
dic = dict(zip(features, count))
dic = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

But I also need the 'country' information from the original dataframe and I don't know how to map the terms back to the original dataframe.

Expected output

```
term        country   domain count 
new york    usa       2
york times  usa       1
york report usa       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the example you provided, not very sure if you provided the correct input for the countvectorizer. If it is a matter of adding the count matrix back to the data frame, you can do it like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'corpus':['This is the first document.',
          'This document is the second document.',
          'And this is the third one.',
          'Is this the first document?']
             })

vectoriser  = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english')
X = vectoriser.fit_transform(df['corpus'])
features = vectoriser.get_feature_names()
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=features,index=df.index)],axis=1)

    corpus  document second second document
0   This is the first document. 0   0
1   This document is the second document.   1   1
2   And this is the third one.  0   0
3   Is this the first document? 0   0
```